# Do Medieval Rabbis speak about the Black Plague?

Tags: history, rabbis

I was wondering if any Rabbis in the Medieval times wrote anything about the Black Plague.

Comment: I'm not sure this is on topic

Comment: @DoubleAA It's arguably about Jewish history which would be on topic

Comment: It seems that there is not a lot written on it. From [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persecution_of_Jews_during_the_Black_Death): "The absence of written accounts may also be attributed to the absence of Jews left to write them." Many Jewish communities were slaughtered during this time period.

Comment: @ezra Jewish history is NOT on topic. It's explicit in the FAQ

Comment: Related: https://www.etzion.org.il/en/halakha/black-death-1347-1351

Comment: There's a Tosfos in Taanis, no? (Mishna talks about going into crisis mode if there's a nearby plague -- even a porcine one -- and Tosfos talks about if it applied to what they were seeing ...)

Comment: @Shalom you know what daf?